# transfer millions of records from Postgres DB to another Postgres, select result is random

Tags: node.js, postgresql, etl

I have requirements to build an API that transfers Postgres query data that contains millions of records into another Postgres DB
The source is hosted on Azure and the Postgres is on Prem.

I tried building transactions using node JS but the issue I had

CODE Below

```js
    // columns: Array<string> contains the columns I want to transfer

    const poolSource = new pg.Pool({
        user: source.user,
        password: source.password,
        database: source.database,
        host: source.host,
        port: source.port,
    });
    const clientDestination = new pg.Client({
        user: destination.user,
        password: destination.password,
        database: destination.database,
        host: destination.host,
        port: destination.port,
    });

    const queries: any = [];

    await clientDestination.connect();

    try {

        let offset = 0;
        const totalRows = 1161509;
        const batchSize = 10000;
        const numBatches = Math.ceil(totalRows / batchSize);

        await clientDestination.query('BEGIN');

        while (true) {
            console.log(offset)

            const result = await poolSource.query(SOURCE_QUERY, [offset, batchSize]);

            if (result.rows.length === 0) {
                console.log("END")
                // No more records to transfer
                break;
            }

            const values = result.rows.map((obj) => Object.values(obj));
            const query = format(
                `INSERT INTO my_table (${columns.join(',')}) VALUES %L`,
                values
            );
            queries.push({
                text: query
            })
            offset += batchSize;
        }
        clientDestination.query(queries);
        await clientDestination.query('COMMIT'); // Rollback transaction if there's an error
    }
    catch (e) {
        await clientDestination.query('ROLLBACK'); // Rollback transaction if there's an error

        console.log("e", e)
        return reply
            .code(constants.SUCCESS_CODE)
            .header(constants.CONTENT_TYPE, constants.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .send({ message: e });
    }
    finally {
        poolSource.end();
        clientDestination.end(); 
        //poolDestination.end();
    }

    return reply
        .code(constants.SUCCESS_CODE)
        .header(constants.CONTENT_TYPE, constants.APPLICATION_JSON)
        .send({ message: "finished" });
```

The Code works totally fine.
the issue I am having in the source DB, when I select from table with the same offset and limit, the select result each time differs from the previous one.
How can I loop through the source data and commit it in the destination with the same rows/values in the source?

Comment: SQL data is unordered by default, trying to maintain order in the transfer is wasted effort. Just make sure your queries use the same `ORDER BY` when doing the `OFFSET/LIMIT`.

Comment: it seems working fine!!
I need to do more testing to make sure my use case is done

Comment: It is not really an option [Limit](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html#SQL-LIMIT): *Thus, using different LIMIT/OFFSET values to select different subsets of a query result will give inconsistent results unless you enforce a predictable result ordering with ORDER BY. This is not a bug; it is an inherent consequence of the fact that SQL does not promise to deliver the results of a query in any particular order unless ORDER BY is used to constrain the order.*